# check if word contains a number or special character

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program to count the total number of valid English words in a text file. In this code, I want to ignore words that contain number/numbers or special characters e.g "word123", "123word ", "word&&", "$name". Currently my program detects words that start with numbers e.g "123number". However cannot detect "number123". Can anyone tell me how should I move forward ? Below is my code:

```
public int wordCounter(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File f = new File(filePath);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    int nonWord = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String regex = "[a-zA-Z].*";

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next();
        if(word.matches(regex)){
            count++;
    }
        else{
            nonWord++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Currently your regexp looks for an alpha followed by any number of characters. I suspect you want it to search for one or more alphas. That would be `"[a-zA-Z]+"` or, more explicitly, `"\\p{Alpha}+"`.

Comment: You also likely need to change the delimiter for the scanner. It matches whitespace by default. You probably need it to match punctuation as well otherwise that will be included in the words. I recommend `scanner.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}|\\p{Space}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the dot:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]*"; // more correctly "[a-zA-Z]+", but both will work here
```

The dot means "any character", but you want a regex that means "only composed of letters".

BTW, you can also express this more succinctly (although arguably less readably) using a POSIX expression:

```
String regex = "\\p{L}+";
```

The regex `\p{L}` means "any letter".

---

To extend the expression to include the apostrophe, which can appear at the start, eg `'tis`, the middle eg `can't` or the end eg `Jesus'`, but not more than once:

```
String regex = "(?!([^']*'){2})['\\p{L}]+";
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried using "[a-zA-z]*" and it worked fine. Any idea how I can make it valid for contractions and possessives as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex **^[a-zA-Z-]+$** for word match.

```
public int wordCounter(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException
{
File f = new File(filePath);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
int nonWord = 0;
int count = 0;
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z-]+$";

while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String word = scanner.next();
    if(word.matches(regex)){
        count++;
}
    else{
        nonWord++;
    }
}
return count;
```

}